# How to check is Christmas tree image edited

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

We three friends between started a funny competition who will find the best method programmatically to check in image Christmas tree toy is edited or not.

I decided to be more unique and after a long search I have chosen [Error Level Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_level_analysis). This method will show edited places more brighter and it could be identified as anomaly easier by human eyes but to identify it programmatically I have a mission:)

I decided to use Python and OpenCV I'm really newbie with it but I think it can done my objective.

I'm still not sure what method to use to find anomaly in image after Error Level Analysis. My opinion the easiest way to find brightest object in image, but practically I found it will not work in all cases, sometimes it will find other regions as brighter or find brightest region in original, not edited image, and return that image is edited.

In most cases after editing object in image object become more brighter but in some cases it can become just specific color, noisier, easier to be recognized by human eyes.

What ideas I have:

1. Firstly, I need to find Christmas tree toy as biggest, main object in image, I'm thinking to add thresholding and find biggest white object and hope it will be my Christmas tree toy.
2. 1.1) Convert image to pixels blocks, compute each block brightness average with formula `(.299 * red) + (.587 * green) + (.114 * blue)`, select brightest blocks, and check are they in my Christmas toy region. If they are return Christmas tree toy was edited.
3. 1.2) Compute whole image pixels brightness average with same formula, compute Christmas tree toy region pixels brightness average. Compare whole image brightness with Christmas tree brightness if toy region is brighter when return image was edited.

But I am really afraid this methods will not work how I expect. Whole image brightness or other image regions in some situations can be brighter than edited region.

Original image (toy angles can various, but it will be always biggest object in image):

[image]

Original image after Error Level Analysis:

[image]

First edited image (changed color, added some noise):

[image]

First edited image after Error Level Analysis:

[image][image]

Second edited image after Error Level Analysis:

[image]

Comment: _We three friends started a funny competition_ Then why are you cheating asking here? ;D

Comment: I'm not cheating I have chosen Error Level Analysis because in my opinion it's best method and I have to prove it, my friends will choose other methods and will try to prove it as well. How we do it and from where we get help to do it will be on our side it will be not cheating:) Thanks for comment anyway!:)

Comment: Interesting question. You only want to do it in this photo or there is more photos? If moro photos is same toy in all photos only from different angles?

Comment: Thanks for question. There is more photos with same toy all of them very similar only differs angles from where photo was taken. For beginning I need solution even for this one photo:) How you think looking for brightest regions could it work?

Comment: From the Wikipedia page you linked: *One of the experts, Hany Farid, said about error level analysis that "It incorrectly labels altered images as original and incorrectly labels original images as altered with the same likelihood".* -- He's saying that the method is BS.